# summing scanf'ed digits sometimes fails under old compiler

Tags: c

I have the following code that adds the input number. 
When i enter 12345, it gives me the correct result but when i enter 56789, it gives me wrong result.

Any help will be appreciated...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
int d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, sum, number, n;
clrscr();
scanf("%d", &number);
printf("number=%d\n",number);
n=number;
d1=n % 10;
n=n / 10;
d2=n % 10;
n=n / 10;
d3=n% 10;
n=n / 10;
d4=n% 10;
n=n / 10;
d5=n;
sum=d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5;
printf ("sum of digits =%d\n", sum);
getch();
}
```

Output result in picture..[image]

Comment: Use a `long` instead of an `int`

Comment: Good old Turbo C++. I hadn't seen someone using it in over a decade. There are much better alternatives nowadays, you really should stop using such a dinosaur of an IDE!

Comment: rofl! I haven't seen this IDE for a long time :D

Comment: I would love to get my hands on a copy of this compiler.  Just for fun.

Comment: Note that this code runs as intended under MSVC10.

Comment: @JohnDibling, I'm not sure I want to know your idea of fun. Best of luck with that.

Comment: @JohnDibling - are you sure? It shouldn't even *compile* under MSVC10 (no return type for `main()`).

Comment: @Robᵩ:  Well, I had to tweak the code a bit to make it legit C++, but I didn't change the logic.  At least, I don't think I changed the logic.

Comment: @Robᵩ Doesn't MSVC support C89/C90? Then the "implicit int" rule comes to the rescue. You have an unspecified termination status since there's no `return` at the end of `main`, but meh.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Sorry, I presumed C++, given the title. You are correct, of course, for C.

Comment: @Robᵩ Yes, the title is C++, tags both, but the includes are C. It should compile under MSVC (and others, in C89 mode) if compiled as C, but under no compiler if compiled as C++. (I made the other mistake, looked pretty much only at the code.)

Answer (score 11):

You're probably overflowing the variables, try using `long` instead of `int`. For a 16-bit `int`, the range is `-32768` to `32767`. You can easily test this out by printing `sizeof(int)`, which will probably be `2` (16 bits) instead of the more common `4` (32 bits).

For Pete's sake, **stop using Turbo C++**. There are countless better alternatives out there.

Comment: I am not agree, there is only division, 56789 even fit in an unsigned short...
Is he running on a 16 bits computer ?

Comment: Could you add a bit more emphasis on the "stop using Turbo C++" bit? I mean I had to quickly find a bucket to throw up into on seeing that screenshot.

Comment: @benjarobin the underlying platform plays some part, but not all. For most 64-bit computers, an `int` is still 32 bits. It's mostly up to the compiler.

Comment: @benjarobin, no, this is right, it is a classic overflow. And yes it looks like the `int` on this "compiler" is a 16-bit signed variable.

Comment: Haha really rocking it old skool. I mean seriously though ... WTF? Also your code is C not C++.